# Creating a recursive function to add a node to a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I am pretty new to pointers, one of my practice problems is to add a node to a linked-list recursively. This code works but I am wondering if this is the correct way to go about this problem.

```
void addNode(node* head){
    if (head->next != NULL) 
        addNode(head->next);

    if (head->next == NULL) {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        head->next = newNode;
  }
}
```

Comment: _"but I am wondering if this is the correct way to go about this problem"_ Certainly not. Recursion is the completely wrong approach.

Comment: Our professor wants a recursive solution.

Comment: Well, then I'm out. I don't deal with _crazy professors_ and _mad doctors_.

Comment: Test it. Test case one: add an element to an empty list. Did it work?

Comment: @n.m. depends on the representation of empty list. NULL is not the only possibility. with head sentinels, yes it would work.

Comment: @WillNess I know, that's why I'm asking if it works.

Comment: @n.m. It works, our test code in main provides a head pointer that points a struct node. To be more general, ill tweak it to handle an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspicious about two things in your code.

1. What the data type `node` is and whether it includes some data fields that you need to somehow initialize. Currently a default constructor will be called, so all nodes in the linked list, added using your function, will be the same. That may or may not be OK. (Depending on what your prof had in mind. This is a homework question after all).
2. Another issue that is not quite clear, is that you assume the linked list is always non-empty. If head is null your function will not work. I doubt that this is OK.

Comment: The node is simply a struct with a field for an int and of course a pointer to the next node. Our test code given assumes main has a head pointer that points to a node.

Comment: I see what you are saying and now it makes sense. Ill tweak it, thanks a ton!